# Select Timestamp By Time Ignoring Date

Tags: mysql, select, time, timestamp

I am trying to "SELECT" a time range while ignoring the date portion of a "TIMESTAMP" field (09-09-11 10:23:03).

The query below works but has huge performance costs...

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Time LIKE '10:09:13'
```

What is the fastest way to do this on a table with 1/2-1 million rows without using the "LIKE" command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE TIME(Time) = '10:09:13'
```

That should do it.

Comment: Wow, that works a lot faster than LIKE. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: `LIKE` relied on implicit cast of your `TIMESTAMP` to `VARCHAR`, which is costly. This option uses the natural type of the timestamp, hence is faster.